# How to send array in $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I want to send my array through session. Here is my code:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, trim($query1));
                if(!$result)
                {
                die('INVALID QUERY: '.mysqli_error($conn));
                }       
                while ($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
                {
                    echo ("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[2]</td><td>$data[3]</td><td>$data[4]</td><td>$data[5]</td><td>$data[6]</td><td>$data[7]</td><td>$data[8]</td></tr>");
            $temp[] = $data[0];             
                }   
$_SESSION['data'] = $temp;
```

But I now have only fails. And in another php file, want to display these values.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $key) {
    # code...
}
```

How I can save my variable into $_SESSION?

Comment: SO what is not working?

Comment: @sgtBOSE, I cant get values from $_SESSION['data'].

Comment: Are you sure `$temp` is not empty at the time of assigning?

Comment: session_start() at the begining or not????

Comment: @sgtBOSE, yes i sure, i checked it.

Comment: It seems session not is working. Session depends on the cookies so please check the cookies permission in your browser

Comment: Have you started the session on those pages?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this might help you .

```
function sessionStore($sessionKey,$value) {
    $sessionValue = null;
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $sessionValue = json_encode($value);
    }
    else{
        $sessionValue = $value;
    }

    $_SESSION[$sessionKey] = $sessionValue;
}

function sessionRetrieveAll($sessionKey){

    $value = $_SESSION[$sessionKey];

    $result = json_decode($value,true);

    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        return $result;
    }

    return $value;
}

function sessionRetrieve($sessionKey,$arrayKey = null){
    $arr = $this->sessionRetrieveAll($sessionKey);

    if(!is_array($arr)){
        return $arr;
    }
    else if($arrayKey != null){
        return isset($arr[$arrayKey]) ? $arr[$arrayKey] : null;
    }

    return $arr;

}
```

And you can implement like this

```
    $this->sessionStore('test',['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd']);
    print_r($this->sessionRetrieve('test')); //Returns array
    echo $this->sessionRetrieve('test','a'); // Returns 'b'

    $this->sessionStore('test2','just string');
    echo $this->sessionRetrieve('test2'); // Returns 'just string'
```

Cheers !!!